# how to get Template Instance (life cycle) in the mocha test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js, meteor-blaze

I am using mocha to write test cases for blaze templates. I want to get the template instance in the test how can i get that.
Here is the code I am using now.

NOTE: invoking (rendering) the Template

```
var view = Blaze.renderWithData(ourTemplate, data, el);
```

In return I am getting the BlazeView object.

But I want to get TemplateInstance (same object which we get in a Template helper function by calling

```
var templateInstance=Template.instance();
```

Any suggestions.